# Ant: Malformed \uxxxx encoding in propertyfile task

Tags: regex, ant, encoding

I get the error below with an Ant skript I wrote.

I already did some googling and found out, that the problem lies with strings containing \u, which happens under Windows because of the directory separator. I changed all those to / but the error remains.

There are definitely no remaining \u strings in my script.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
```

The error occurs when executing the propertyfile task, so I examined the file I want to change. This on the other hand contains multiple \u strings. The file has no relation to ant though, it's a borland project file (xml) which contains one line like [someParameter]=[someValue].

I just want to increase [someValue] by 1.

So my question is:

Can the property file I want to change cause the error mentioned

and if the answer is "yes",

What can I do, **other than** doing it with a regex task (like finding the line, propertyregex-ing the value, math+1 the value and regex-replacing the value)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

i know that this question was asked a while ago but i stumbled on it without an answer, on another site i found (http://www.coderanch.com/t/107014/tools/Malformed-uxxxx-encoding-error) i found that this could happen when instead of "\" for file destinations you should be using "/" because of how parsing works/ Hope this helps.

Comment: I confirm that changing \ to / in my .properties files solved the issue.

Comment: I encountered the same issue because I changed some / with \ in a properties file which referenced by mvn.

Comment: My case is someone has put an invalid code `\u<wrongcode>`.

Comment: Cool! replacing \ with / of my windows path in my .properties fixed the issue.

Comment: Since our team is mutli-OS, I opted for / instead of \\, but that was it.

Comment: I got the same problem with maven, it worked after I removed .m2 folder, something got corrupted there. I know is not about ant, but it might help the people arriving here.

Answer (score 67):

go to your .m2 directory in home directory and for every dependence delete the "resolver-status.properties". You can do that using

```
find ~/.m2/ -name resolver-status.properties -delete
```

It will find all "resolver-status.properties" and -delete flag will delete them.

Now reload maven project.

Comment: This worked, Thanks for sharing. but can you please explain why this worked ?

Comment: @Chetanacharekar I got malformed issue in one of my dependency  while running install in Intellij, i deleted that one resolver-status.properties file. After that i got issue with same file in another dependency. So i ran this command to delete all such resolver-status.properties  files and it worked.

Comment: No idea why this worked but it did, thanks @mahipalkeizer

Comment: what will be the equivalent to windows command?

Answer (score 13):

In my case it was maven throwing this error.

```
[INFO] Building some-prj 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.508 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-31T08:00:30-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I had to rename the .m2 dir

`mv ~/.m2 ~/m2_20210831`

and restart maven build

`mvn clean package`

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  48.927 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-31T08:04:56-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The currently selected solution (with most upvotes) did not solve the issue for me; Nuking the ~/.m2 directory, as suggested here did though. Must have been a corrupted package or something.

Comment: This is solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 8):

You go in .m2 and search resolver-status.properties after then delete all files related and re-build your project. It will build success.

[image]

Comment: this worked for windows

Comment: Works for me too on windows! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Use the double backslash ("\\") like "abc\\user" which is equivalent to "abc\user" and will solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

> grep -lrnw ~/.m2 -e '\u0000' | xargs rm

searches your m2 folder for malformed files and deletes them.

then reload maven project.

Answer (score 2):

Open the `.m2` folder and search for `resolver-status.properties`. Then, delete all files related to that search. Finally do a `clean install` using Maven.

Answer (score 1):

deleting all the "resolver-status.properties" files and re-building the project worked

Answer (score 0):

first you should try running the ant script with the **debug flag** to determine which file is causing the issue
in Eclipse you do this by going to

```
Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations... > Main
```

and adding "-d" (without the quotes) to "Arguments"

then **try editing the file in Eclipse** as some editors (e.g. "Wordpad") may mess up the file

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found out that the problem is due to the local.cfg file encoding. If we created(edited) the local.cfg file using wordpad or other non code editing software, it changes the file encoding. So when ant tries to load the local configuration file ( due to the line       in the dspace-installer/ build.xml file, it expects ASCII character encoded, .cfg file. So when it gets the UTF encoded file the exception raises. 
Solution:
remove the local.cfg file, create it again using a code editing softwares like Visual Studio code or other, and edit/write the necessary configuration settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Renaming my **Repository** folder in `C:\Users\\{user-name}\\.m2` and running the command again worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a concrete dependency causing this annoying error. I had

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ops4j.pax.exam/pax-exam-junit4 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
    <artifactId>pax-exam-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

After replacing it by:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ops4j.pax.exam/pax-exam-junit4 -->
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
        <artifactId>pax-exam-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.redhat-1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I found that clearing my local maven cache (the "repository" folder inside of ".m2") solved the problem for me.

There are some suggestions here to rename/delete the whole .m2 folder, but that would get rid of your settings.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

If this issue is related to maven then we can simply delete "repository folder" in ".m2" directory/path and trigger build for the project again. It should give a build success after it.

Answer (score 0):

This command will recursively delete all files matching the pattern "resolver-status.properties*" within the ".m2" directory for Windows systems. This should resolve the issue of Malformed \uxxxx encoding in propertyfile.

Get-ChildItem -Path $HOME.m2 -Recurse -Filter "resolver-status.properties*" | Remove-Item -Force

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but I found a different solution. I realized that I had an error in the file inside my project (Runtime Error)

I have a file with name of `fieldNames.properties`

```
sarBranchCode=\u0633\u0631\u067E\u0631\u0633\u062A\u06CC
branchCode=\u0634\u0639\u0628\u0647
faslName=\u0639\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u0633\u0631\u0641\u0635\u0644
fasl=\u0633\u0631\u0641\u0635\u0644 8\u0631\u0642\u0645\u06CC
faslM=\u0633\u0631\u0641\u0635\u0644 \u0645\u0639\u06CC\u06CC\u0646
faslK=\u0633\u0631\u0641\u0635\u0644 \u062F\u0641\u062A\u0631\u06A9\u0644
e5=\u0633\u0631\u0641\u0635\u0644 e5
accountNumber=\u0634\u0645\u0627\u0631\u0647 \u062D\u0633\u0627\u0628
balance=\u0645\u0627\u0646\u062F\u0647
bed=\u0628\u062F\u0647\u06A9\u0627\u0631 \u0633\u0627\u0644\u06CC\u0627\u0646\u0647
bes=\u0628\u0633\u062A\u0627\u0646\u06A9\u0627\u0631 \u0633\u0627\u0644\u06CC\u0627\u0646\u0647
fasl11=\u0633\u0631\u0641\u0635\u0644 11 \u0631\u0642\u0645\u06CC
fasl11M=\u0633\u0631\u0641\u0635\u062\u0644 \u0645\u0639\u06CC\u0646 11 \u062F\u0641\u062A\u0631\u06A9\u0644
```

[image]

My error was in line of 15 (last line). then I removed line of 15

Answer (score -1):

You can try running this, I was getting the same issue with my maven project.

```
grep -lrnw  ~/.m2 -e '\u0000' | xargs rm
```