# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding while mvn install

Tags: java, macos, maven, encoding, java-8

While running mvn install in my project, I end up with this error. While a lot of answers and resources point out errors in `/` vs `\`, I want to mention that I have no local changes and this repo just works fine for others in my team. It worked fine for me as well before.

*Running on Mac Os 10.15.7 with JDK 1.8.0_291*

Please find the full stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
    at java.util.Properties.loadConvert (Properties.java:672)
    at java.util.Properties.load0 (Properties.java:455)
    at java.util.Properties.load (Properties.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.TrackingFileManager.read (TrackingFileManager.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.read (DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkMetadata (DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolve (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolveMetadata (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionRangeResolver.getVersions (DefaultVersionRangeResolver.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionRangeResolver.resolveVersionRange (DefaultVersionRangeResolver.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel (DefaultModelResolver.java:197)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally (DefaultModelBuilder.java:1070)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent (DefaultModelBuilder.java:846)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:337)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:292)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:523)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
```

I have already tried the following:

1. Reinstalled java on my mac
2. Reinstalled maven
3. Tried to invalidate cache and restart IntelliJ multiple times.

Comment: I having similar issues. Rolled back all local changes and still got the issue. Worked earlier today and pretty sure I haven't had any updates.

Comment: @SebastianL Please find my answer, it worked for me

Comment: Windows User: Search for resolver-status.properties files in entire .m2 folder using file-explorer then delete all those searched files and rerun maven command. It will start working

Answer (score 187):

For me it turned out to be a corrupted dependency as well.
I did not want to go through the process of setting up the debugger, so decided to look for files containing `\u0000` in my `~/.m2` directory by running:

```
grep -rnw ~/.m2 -e '\u0000'
```

after that you will get the files which are corrupted, delete those files and then build the maven.

Note that you have to specify your repository folder if you configured it different to the default. Read your `~/.m2/settings.xml` and use the value from `localRepository` instead. E.g.:

```
<settings>
  <localRepository>/else/where</localRepository>
```

use:

```
grep -rnw /else/where -e '\u0000'
```

and if you want all these files removed, pipe the file names to `xargs rm`:

```
grep -lrnw /else/where -e '\u0000' | xargs rm
```

If you have a large amount of files in your .m2 repository, you can fasten the removal by using the find command:

```
find  ~/.m2 -name "resolver-status.properties" -exec grep -H -e '\u0000' {} \; | sed -r 's/:.*$//g' | xargs rm
```

Comment: This is what worked for me. On macOS, I ran "grep -r -e '\u0000' ~/.m2" and it yielded the correct resolver-ststus.properties that, after deletion of the dependency, was replaced by a correct one and things worked.

Comment: I need to brush up on `grep` options. This is more concise than what I did:
```find  ~/.m2 -name "resolver-status.properties" -print -exec grep "u0" {} \;```

Comment: For me it was one of the _remote.repositories files that was broken

Comment: in case people are struggling in windows, you can run this command inside .m2 directory `FINDSTR /S /M "u0" resolver-status.properties` to findout corrupted files.

Comment: Thanks to Manish Bansal for his help, I was struggling w/ this issue on windows!!

Comment: A combination of all these suggestions: `grep -lrnw ~/.m2/repository --include 'resolver-status.properties' -e '\u0000' | xargs rm`

Comment: sometime | xargs rm doesn't work so better manually delete the folders under ~/m2/com/xyz etc and rebuild the project can help.

Answer (score 89):

To find which file is malformed (as to not have to delete your entire Maven repository) you can debug it like so:

1. Add a breakpoint to the relevant line in `java.util.Properties` (as detailed in the error stack trace) and then run any Maven action in debug mode.

[image]

2. When the code hits that breakpoint, find and select `TrackingFileManager.read(File)` in the call stack.

[image]

3. Now find path of the file that caused the issue.

[image]

4. The file is indeed malformed... Delete the file (and Maven will re-download it during the next action).

[image]

5. The correct file (after having been deleted and re-downloaded):

[image]

Comment: This is actually a great answer with the step by step details to find the exact file. Step 1 (adding a breakpoint in IntelliJ and using it with maven) can be setup using the following: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2020/08/20/maven-debugging-intellij/

Comment: Does not work if you have compiled dependecies.

Comment: Java should consider adding option to reveal file path itself rather than debugging and putting breakpoints all the time.

Comment: thank you very much for this great answer - it really helped a much to solve our problem. Spring Boot had a really strange error message but the maven build error leaded us to your answer!

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 32):

I wrote an answer for another [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043037/ant-malformed-uxxxx-encoding-in-propertyfile-task/71408534#71408534), this is similar issue. Below Solution worked for me.

go to your .m2 directory in home directory and for every dependence delete the "resolver-status.properties". You can do that using

```
find ~/.m2/ -name resolver-status.properties -delete
```

It will find all "resolver-status.properties" and -delete flag will delete them.

Now reload maven project.

Comment: [FYI] I got malformed issue in one of my dependency while running install in Intellij, i deleted that one resolver-status.properties file. After that i got issue with same file in another dependency. So i ran this command to delete all such resolver-status.properties files and it worked

Comment: Windows User: Search for resolver-status.properties files in entire .m2 folder using file-explorer then delete all those searched files and rerun maven command. It will start working

Answer (score 26):

In my case the problem was in the 3rd party library, incorrect charаcters somehow were saved to the **resolver-status.properties** file (example of incorrect line: `maven-metadata-nexus-releases.xml.lastUpda\u0000\u0000\....`) which is located under the `~/.m2/repository/path-to-the-library`. Just removed the folder with the library and rebuilt the project.

Comment: How do these files get corrupted? Is it a bug with mvn or am I abusing mvn in a way that it shouldn't be used?

Comment: I get this problem over and over again!

Comment: It seems to be a bug in Maven 3.8.1. The issue reappeared again and again even after deleting the libraries from the local Maven repository. Upgrading to latest Maven 3.8.3 and rebuilding with that version fixed the problem.

Answer (score 23):

Actually most of those answers are correct, but a little bit incomplete. Message shows up, because `resolver-status.properties` files get corrupted and they contain \u0000 as shown in micycle's answer. It sometimes helps to delete corrupted files and rerun maven command. Sometimes problem disappears and sometimes not. The question emerges WHY those files get corrupted. Well, it seems that maven contains a bug in resolver: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOLVER-216

It seems that synchronization of multiple threads responsible for resolving dependencies is broken and in some conditions multiple threads resolve the same artifact and they break `resolver-status.properties` as shown by micycle.

In case your build still does not complete successfully despite deleting broken files you might want to limit resolver threads to one. To do that use JVM property:

```
-Daether.metadataResolver.threads=1
```

If you are using IntelliJ Idea use `Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Maven->Runner` field `VMOptions`:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1]

After making this change remember to delete broken files (or whole `.m2` directory) because once the files become corrupted they won't be fixed. Then rerun your Maven build.

Comment: For me it was one of the _remote.repositories files that was broken

Comment: Please note that today I've found a file that was broken, because it contained just `\u`, so not only string `\u0000` may break your files.

Comment: @Rafi It's total crazy, in my case it breaks with c:\user\... while c:\temp\... is working only because there is this u check: if(aChar == 'u') in java.util.Property loadConvert() This is some kind of a bug is it???!

Answer (score 20):

I removed all artifacts from my ~/.m2 directory and re-ran mvn build.
This time, build succeeded!

Comment: That could have worked but not a great choice if you already have a big repo to be downloaded again.

Comment: I would do this and wait for 5 minutes over spending whole day to pin-point the bad dependency!!

Comment: Windows User: Search for resolver-status.properties files in entire .m2 folder using file-explorer then delete all those searched files and rerun maven command. It will start working

Answer (score 8):

You don't actually need to delete the whole local maven repo, just the **resolver-status.properties** files in there, for mac:

`find .m2/ -name resolver-status.properties -delete`

works as a charm. I've even added an alias, as I use it pretty frequently, once in a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 6):

removing .m2 folder and re-installing the dependency worked for me.

Comment: That could have worked but not a great choice if you already have a big repo to be downloaded again. Also, this is same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/68532125/725306

Comment: Windows User: Search for resolver-status.properties files in entire .m2 folder using file-explorer then delete all those searched files and rerun maven command. It will start working

Answer (score 6):

Go to .m2 repository, then run the below cmd from there
FINDSTR /S /M "u0" resolver-status.properties
This will enlist all the corrupted resolver properties files, delete them and you are good to GO!

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution for this issue for Windows users (didn't see any better solution for Windows users).

Open command prompt from .m2/repository/ folder and run the below FINDSTR command:

```
FINDSTR /S /M "u0" resolver-status.properties
```

This command will filter out the resolver-status.properties that has corrupt encoding.

Once you find the list of resolver-status.properties files, just delete them and then build your app.

Comment: This finds and deletes the files in one (powershell command):

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "resolver-status.properties" |
  Select-String -Pattern "u0" |
  Select-Object -Unique Path |
  Foreach-Object { Remove-Item $_.Path }

Answer (score 3):

deleting "resolver-status.properties" under

.m2\repository\kr\motd\maven\os-maven-plugin

resolve problem for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Problem is likely in one of your dependencies (same as suggested by Alexey). For me the issue was to find the right dependency that got resolver-status.properties corrupted. What helped was running mvn clean install in debug mode (using Intellig configuration debug) and putting th endpoint in Properties.java (exact line should be in a stacktrace when you run with -e or -X option). In debug you can easily find which dependency is corrupted and remove only this dependency instead of entire .m2 catalog

Answer (score 1):

Found out that the java version that maven was pointing to was different from the java version I was using.
Seems like maven always points to the latest version of java.

First check if this is the issue by running `mvn --version`

If there is a mismatch in java version set JAVA_HOME by running

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

Now run `mvn --version`. Maven should point to the right Java version.

When you run `mvn install` next time, maven automatically picks up the version set in JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when we build the project or run any Maven command for the first time,  dependencies or properties are getting saved in the repository folder (default location: ~/.m2/repository).

I have used multiple Maven and Java versions in the past, so some files are corrupted or valid for those specific versions.

I deleted this "repository" folder then built the project with Maven, and this time it built successfully.

Comment: Although very general answer it could written better to emphasize the solution. I am not sure f rebuild is an actual answer here

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from 3.8.1 to 3.8.6 fixed the problem.

Comment: Regarding the downvote: I'm the only one who solved this problem with a newer version of maven. It's also mentioned by other people in comments in this question. The maven resolver was upgraded in 3.8.6 and it looks that it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a Global search for  resolver-status.properties and delete that file and restart the IDE. That should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, switch to directory

```
cd ~/.m2
```

then execute command line :

```
find ./ -name resolver-status.properties |xargs -I {} ls -l {}
```

it will delete error files which was created by error building, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Some missing info while trying to fetch dependency. Steps to fix:

1. You can get more info about the dependency with issue by running this-

> mvn clean install -e -X

2. Just before the final build failure error, you'll find dependency with the issue. Msg would be like-

> Could not find metadata
> com.xx1.xx2.service-clients::1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
> in local (/Users/<user.name>/.m2/repository)

3. Go to /Users/<user.name>/.m2/repository, and delete the dependency path-

> cd /Users/<user.name>/.m2/repository

> rm -r com.xx1.xx2.service-clients

4. On rerun of mvn clean install, same dependency will be downloaded from source to local.