# org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding for MAC

Tags: java, macos, maven

I'm running on MAC and I was running mvn install on my Java project and I got this error. I checked online for a whole day but most answers are about the / and , however I have no local changes and my team could build the repo fine, and I could build successfully before. Also I saw someone has faced the same issue but after they fixed the JAVA version it worked fine for them.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68003423/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-malformed-uxxxx-encoding-while-mvn-install?newreg=96abc52a5b8e46d9a72155ef37f33c81. I have tried all the methods and they are not working:
I have tried reinstalling JAVA, MAVEN, also updating JAVA/MAVEN version. I recall I faced similar issue before and when I switch JAVA/MAVEN to older version it worked fine, but this time it does not work anymore. Could anyone help with it? I really appreciate it.
I tried with MAVEN 3.8, MAVEN 3.5, MAVEN 3.3 and they are all having this issue. I was using JAVA11 and having some issues then I switched to JAVA8 and uninstalled JAVA11.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T11:41:47-05:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven@3.3/3.3.9_1/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_292, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_CA, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.16", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/local/Cellar/maven@3.3/3.3.9_1/libexec/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from /usr/local/Cellar/maven@3.3/3.3.9_1/libexec/conf/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /Users/bill.chen/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.karauctionservices.itss.scm:parent:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local 
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
    at java.util.Properties.loadConvert(Properties.java:574)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:391)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.TrackingFileManager.read(TrackingFileManager.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.read(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkMetadata(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolve(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolveMetadata(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.resolveVersion(DefaultVersionResolver.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:246)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1000)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:800)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:329)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:469)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:438)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:401)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:419)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:410)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph(DefaultMaven.java:491)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    ... 11 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/InternalErrorException
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to the community. Unfortunately, we can't help you with the current state of your question, as we can't reproduce. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help us help you.

Answer (score 7):

You can delete the downloaded packages inside repository in your /.m2/repository/** folder where your maven dependency downloads(Take a backup for safer side).

In your IDE(sts or eclipse), try to do maven build(clean install).

Hope your issue resolved.

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually did this and maven build again, and it's working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting my entire local maven repository, I tried to add a "Java exception breakpoint" for the `IllegalArgumentException` exception in my eclipse IDE.

So I launched the maven launch configuration in debug mode, and the IDE stopped when the exception was launched. I navigated the stack watching at local variables and arguments, and I quickly found the corrupted file.

In my case was `resolver-status.properties` in `wagon-webdav` library, inside the maven repository. I deleted the folder and the problem has gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

Someone on SO suggested to check for '\u0000' occurrences using command-line grep, but I needed to check for '\u000' until I found the "perpetrator" file.

```
$ grep -rnw ~/.m2 -e '\u000'
grep: /home/myusername/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/saxon/saxon/9.1.0.8/saxon-9.1.0.8.jar: binary file matches
grep: /home/myusername/.m2/repository/com/nimbusds/lang-tag/resolver-status.properties: binary file matches
```

I deleted this folder with the second search hit, `/home/myusername/.m2/repository/com/nimbusds`, now it works again.

(Weird, I thought there was an answer like this here that I just wanted to update. But not finding it, I wrote this new one.)